# What is the order of evaluation of function arguments in C++/CLI

Tags: function, c++-cli, arguments

As it is known the order of evaluation of function arguments is undefined in C++. However in C# function arguments are evaluated from left to right.
So the question arises: what is the order of evaluation of function arguments in C++/CLI? Does C++/CLI behave the same way as C++ relative to function arguments or as C#?
I saw the ECMA #372 but I did not find any words on this question. Could someone give me a reference to a normative document where there is written what is the order of evaluation of function arguments in C++/CLI?

Comment: Not undefined, but unspecified. It's an important distinction.

Comment: It is unspecified.  The lack of a guarantee does not constitute a promise, you cannot make any assumptions.  The language spec does in fact promise that array indexing expression order is undefined, in itself enough to worry enough about argument evaluation order.

Comment: In C++ the order of evaluation is unspecified, and this is true for C++/CLI as well. And even if it wasn't, it would still be wise not to rely on evaluation order, as in any other C++ program, e.g. for portability reasons.

Comment: I am sorry. I meant indeed the word unspecified. :) But what about C++/CLI?

Comment: Kris Vandermotten I am not sure that it is the same as in C++. The problem that the order of evaluation of functions arguments in C# is well-defined. They are evalueated from left to right. Moreover if you will use the MS VC++ compiler with option /CLR then the compiler starts also to evaluate function arguments from left to right instead of from right to left in the classical C++ as it does usually. So it would be not bad if someone could reference to some normative document.

Answer (score 1):

The [C++/CLI spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-372.pdf) does *not* mention it (as you say), and, as far as I can tell, the guaranteed order of evaluation [is specified in the **C#** language spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691335.aspx), as opposed to being something specific to `.NET`.

Since C++/CLI compiles to [IL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) (just like e.g. VB.NET) I would say that nothing can be inferred for C++/CLI from the fact that *C#*, the language, guarantees anything.

Therefore it appears to be just as unspecified as for normal C++. Whether any rules of the .NET `IL` cause certain evaluation order, I cannot say.